# iOS6 Trying to Create UITabBarController from UIView

Tags: ios, tabbar

I'm trying to programatically create a UITabBar from a UIViewController. I am currently using this algorithm. However, I met up with a problem. May anyone tell me what I am lacking?

```
-(void)loadView{
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.view = contentView;

    TabControllerHelper *tabControllerHelper = [[TabControllerHelper alloc]initWithNibName:@"TabControllerHelper" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    tabControllerHelper.title = @"First";

    TabControllerHelper *tabControllerHelper1 = [[TabControllerHelper alloc]initWithNibName:@"TabControllerHelper" bundle:nil];
    tabControllerHelper1.title = @"Second";

    //dvdInfoController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dvdicon.png"];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

    // Set each tab to show an appropriate view controller
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabControllerHelper, tabControllerHelper1, nil]];
    [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];

}
```

The error I received:

```
2012-12-11 01:34:27.581 SampleUITabView[7134:c07] -[__NSCFType _tabBarItemClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7574230
2012-12-11 01:34:27.582 SampleUITabView[7134:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType _tabBarItemClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7574230'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: What is possibly happening is that you just added a subview and the subview has buttons which are triggering a method which does not exist. The subview does not necessarily know that its controller is the tab bar controller

Comment: You are calling a `selector` called `_tabBarItemClicked:` that the controller doesn't know about. Quite clear really in this line `-[__NSCFType _tabBarItemClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7574230`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some things which is "ViewController Containment". One approach could be to leave loadView alone and just let it do the basic stuff.

And in viewDidLoad do the view controller containment like

self addChildController ...
self.view addSubview:...
childController didMoveToParent ...

Because by just adding the tab bar controllers view as a subview, you are not necessarily getting the tabbar controllers behavior.